# Can't delete dynamically added table row

Tags: jquery, dynamic, row, addition

I am pretty new to jquery and I want to add and delete table rows by
clicking the add or remove image.

The adding button works perfectly and a manually added row with a delete button works perfectly, but if I add a new row and then click the delete button for the new row, it does nothing.

I have tried searching google and testing all the answers but none seem to work for me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    var idCount = 0;
                    idCount++;
                    var new_row="<tr><td><span style='float:left; margin-left:20px;'>IP:&nbsp;</span><input name='ipaddr' type='text' /></td><td><img src='images/delete.png' width='20px' height='20px' id='deleteRow' /></td></tr>";
                    $("table#ipList img#addRow").click(function() {
                            $("table#ipList").append(new_row);
                    });
                    $("table#ipList img#deleteRow").click(function() {
                            //$("img#deleteRow").parents("tr").remove();
                            //$("img#deleteRow").parent().parent().last().remove();
                            $("img#deleteRow").last().parent().parent().remove();
                    });
            });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table id="ipList">
            <tr>
                    <td><span style="float:left; margin-left:20px;">IP:&nbsp;</span><input name="ipaddr" type="text" /></td>
                    <td><img src="images/add.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="addRow" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td><span style="float:left; margin-left:20px;">IP:&nbsp;</span><input name="ipaddr" type="text" /></td>
                    <td><img src="images/delete.png" width="20px" height="20px" id="deleteRow" /></td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: why do you have var new_row commented?

Comment: And also, if ID's are unique you don't need `table#ipList img#addRow`, `#addRow` would be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use delegation this way:

*But IDs must be unique on context page!*

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var idCount = 0;
     idCount++;
     $("#ipList").on('click', "#addRow", function () {
         $("#ipList").append(new_row);
     });
     $("#ipList").on('click', "#deleteRow", function () {
         $("#deleteRow").closest('tr').remove();
     });
  });
```

Comment: wow thanks that worked like a charm :)
One last question, how could I append idCount to the new inputs class.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need event delegation. Use the on()  method for this. http://api.jquery.com/on/